# SSL Certificate Authentication Issue 403.7

Tags: tls, certificates, iis

I have been trying to configure SSL for authentication and was unable to resolve this error 403.7 on IIS 7.5 windows 2008r2 vps server. I would like to give access to few computers where client certificate is installed. In order to achieve this I would like to use "iisclientcertificateauthentication" and "mapping".

My questions are:

1. In one to one mapping what should be username? Since in browser we
   do not have option for username while installing certificate.
2. The certificate which is exported as .pfx is it client certificate
   to be distributed?
   since.cert file is the certificate provided by certification company.

I am new to IIS please bear with me.

Comment: You can review two similar post on stack overflow. 1.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131458/403-7-iis-7-5-ssl-client-certificate-authentication-issue 2.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531712/client-ssl-authentication-causing-403-7-error-from-iis

Comment: I have been using plesk panel for installing certificates. Is there any way I can use plesk panel to configure it.

Comment: Used "IUSER" as User name and its working. Thank You.